# Java Bean Validation: Multiple @GroupSequence and class-level constraint

Tags: java, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I am trying to set up a complex bean validation with ordering in a spring mvc environment.

This is what I got so far:

```
@Data // Lombok
@CheckActivationIO(groups = {C1.class})
public class ActivateIO {

    @NotNull(message = "NULL", groups = B1.class)
    @Email(message = "FORMAT", groups = B2.class)
    @InactiveAccount(groups = B3.class)
    private String email;

    @NotNull(message = "NULL", groups = A1.class)
    @Size(min = 10, max = 12, message = "LENGTH", groups = A2.class)
    private String token;
}
```

And the groupSequence Interfaces:

```
@GroupSequence({A1.class, A2.class, A3.class, A4.class})
public interface ASequence {
}

@GroupSequence({B1.class, B2.class, B3.class, B4.class})
public interface BSequence {
}

@GroupSequence({Default.class, C1.class, C2.class})
public interface CSequence {
}
```

This is how the validator is called:

```
validator.validate(activateIO, ASequence.class, BSequence.class, CSequence.class);
```

The goal is to validate email and token independently and only if both are valid, the class level constraint @CheckActivationIO should be executed.

some examples.:

1. email - NULL & token - LENGTH
2. email - FORMAT (& token is valid)
3. (email and token valid) & @CheckActivationIO fails

Using GroupSequences I can do both (attributes independently and class level after attributes) seperately but not together. Any pointers, how the problem can be approached? In this case, the @CheckActivationIO constraint must only be executed if sequence A has passed group A2 and sequence B has passed group B3.

Maybe a little diagram makes it more clear:

[image: parallel and sequential group sequences]

The provided code implements the parallel part of the diagram and works find. I am struggeling with the additional sequential sequence C, which should only be executed if both parallel sequences are valid. Parallel here means, that the corresponding attributes are validated independently in a given order. (A validation error in A does not affect sequence B.

Problem: How can I define a groupSequence that is dependent on multiple other previous groupSequences?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with: "Using GroupSequences I can do both seperately but not together." What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to independently validate the attributes in an ordered manner. Assume custom validators with depend on each other. Therefore, there are the sequences A and B. Only if both sequences are valid, the validation should proceed with the annotations on class level, again ordered (sequence C?). Is there a way to force this behavior? I see that this use-case is highly constructed and maybe not relevant in praxis, but I am trying to understand the limits of this process.

Comment: But that's what your example/setup is doing, right? Or is there a concrete problem with it?

Comment: The example implements the independent validation of both attributes. The problem is with sequence C. It is evaluated in parallel to the other two sequences and not afterwards. I could do this with a sequence again (dropping A and B sequence first), but I cannot combine both approaches.  Can I somehow set sequence C in relation to sequence A and B?

Comment: I think I got you know. In this case you need yet another sequence indeed with the order of ASequence, BSequence and finally CSequence - let's call it ValidationSquence. You then need to call  Validator#validate with this sequence: validator.validate(activateIO, ValidationSquence.class);

Comment: I tried something like this `@GroupSequence({ASequence.class, BSequence.class, C1.class, C2.class})`, the nesting works but A and B are not validated in parallel anymore.

Comment: You could try to create two more sequences ASequenceWithClass and BSequenceWithClass. In the first you add ASequence.class,  C1.class, C2.class and in the second BSequence.class, C1.class, C2.class. Then you call validator.validate(activateIO, ASequenceWithClass.class, BSequenceWithClass.class). Of course this gets now overly complex.

Comment: This doesn't work either. In this case the C1 group can be validated when ASequenceWithClass validated the ASequence without error but it does not wait for BSequence.